# Simple Compass CSS Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, compass-sass, zinnia

I am learning Compass with Django/Zinnia. Running the following to produce css produces an error that I don't really understand. Thanks!

```
cd /var/www/static/zinnia

compass compile ./ --trace
LoadError on line ["36"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:161:in `require'
/var/www/static/zinnia/./config.rb:2:in `get_binding'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:204:in `with_defaults'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:42:in `configuration_for'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:97:in `add_project_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:31:in `add_project_configuration'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:37:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have the Susy extension installed?

Comment: Nope. Followed your trail to http://data.agaric.com/installing-compass-and-sass-susy-ubuntu and installed. Works beautifully now. Thank you! Add the solution and I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compass was not installed. I issued the following per cimmanon's suggestions:

```
gem install compass
gem install compass-susy-plugin
gem install stitch
```

via http://data.agaric.com/installing-compass-and-sass-susy-ubuntu

Also had to install java for compass-validate to work.